# Using formatDisplayField in grouping

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I have 3 columns (orderType, po number, bill id) that I am grouping by and I am using formatDisplayField to add a link/button to each group text so when clicked will open a context menu that will allow my users to add subgroups to that group. I need to pass the immediate row data that pertains to that group. Right now I am doing something sort of hacky and the data isnt specific enough.

**Example:**

A user clicks on the group *`ordertype`* and gets a context menu that says *`Add PO Number`*, they can then add a po number and on that group header they get a context menu that says *`Add Billing Id`*. User can also add a billing id without adding a po number, this is important because this is where my data gets wonky. Lets say grid looks like:

```
OrderGroupType: Direct
    PONumber: 12345
        BillingId: abc

OrderGroupType: Direct
    BillingId: abc
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get the data rows that have to do with the current group so I get all the data from the grid and then search through it and only return rows that equal my group name and then I put that information into a data attribute where I pull the information out in the context menu:

```
groupText: ['Group Type: <b>{0} - {1} Item(s)</b>',
            'PO Number: <b>{0} - {1} Item(s)</b>',
            'Bill To: <b>{0} - {1} Item(s)</b>'
        ],
 formatDisplayField: [
    function (ordgrpTypVal) {
        //all rowData
        var allRowData = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "data");
        //this row data
        var rowData = $.grep(allRowData, function (v) {
            return v.OrderGroupType == grpTypVal;
        });
        var elementId = "groupType_" + grpTypVal.replace(/\s+/g, '') + "_" + i++;
        var newElement = '<span id="' + elementId + '" data-rowdata=\'' + JSON.stringify(rowData).replace(/'/g, "\\'") +'\' class="groupTypeMenu" style="cursor: pointer; color: blue;">' + grpTypVal + '</span>';
        return newElement;
    }
]
```

Where I am going wrong is I then have two more functions in that `formatDisplayField` property where I also set links/button onto the child groups:

```
formatDisplayField: [
    function (grpTypVal) {
        //all rowData
        var allRowData = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "data");
        //this row data
        var rowData = $.grep(allRowData, function (v) {
            return v.OrderGroupType == grpTypVal;
        });
        var elementId = "groupType_" + grpTypVal.replace(/\s+/g, '') + "_" + i++;
        var newElement = '<span id="' + elementId + '" data-rowdata=\'' + JSON.stringify(rowData).replace(/'/g, "\\'") +'\' class="groupTypeMenu" style="cursor: pointer; color: blue;">' + grpTypVal + '</span>';
        return newElement;
    },
    function (poVal) {
        if (poVal !== null) {
            //all rowData
            var allRowData = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "data");
            //this row data
            var rowData = $.grep(allRowData, function (v) {
                return v.PoNumber == poVal;
            });
            var elementId = "PoNum_" + poVal.replace(/\s+/g, '') + "_" + i++;
            var newElement = '<span id="' + elementId + '" data-rowdata=\'' + JSON.stringify(rowData).replace(/'/g, "\\'") + '\'  class="poMenu" style="cursor: pointer; color: blue;">' + poVal + '</span>';
            return newElement;
        }
        else
            return null;
    },
    function (billToVal, val, props, index, obj) {
        if (billToVal !== null) {
            //all rowData
            var allRowData = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "data");
            //this row data
            var rowData = $.grep(allRowData, function (v) {
                return v.BillToId == billToVal;
            });
            var elementId = "BillTo_" + billToVal.replace(/\s+/g, '') + "_" + i++;
            var newElement = '<span id="' + elementId + '" data-rowdata=\'' + JSON.stringify(rowData).replace(/'/g, "\\'") + '\' class="billToMenu" style="cursor: pointer; color: blue;">' + billToVal + '</span>';
            return newElement;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
]
```

This breaks down when I have a billing id that has a parent po number with the same billing id. It could also break down if I had two po numbers that were exactly the same in two different order groups.

So my question is how can I get the data that pertains to the group more reliably? I'd prefer that I only get rowData that has to do with the specific group. I could see that happening if I could get more data, maybe something like:

```
formatDisplayField: [
    function (billToVal, val, props, index, obj) {
        if (billToVal !== null) {
            //all rowData
            var allRowData = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "data");
            //this row data
            var rowData = $.grep(allRowData, function (v) {
                return v.BillToId == billToVal **&& v.PoNumber == obj.PoNumber && v.OrderGroupType == obj.OrderGroupType;**
            });
            var elementId = "BillTo_" + billToVal.replace(/\s+/g, '') + "_" + i++;
            var newElement = '<span id="' + elementId + '" data-rowdata=\'' + JSON.stringify(rowData).replace(/'/g, "\\'") + '\' class="billToMenu" style="cursor: pointer; color: blue;">' + billToVal + '</span>';
            return newElement;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
]
```

The fiddle below illustrates my issue; to see it working click MANUALS and choose edit, you will see it highlights the rows under manuals to orange, however, if you click on `1` under `DSPO` and click edit, you will see it colors all the rows that have a billing id of `1` instead of just the row group you chose... The rows that are going to be edited should color orange.
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/y3llowjack3t/dv4v8mmz/)

Any help would be phenomenal, I have tried lots of different things and the data is just not reliable. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that your code too complex as it could be. The first very important problem: your input data don't contain `id` property with unique value. You place for example `JSON.stringify(rowData)` instead of comma separated list of `rowid` only because your input data has no `id` value. If the value of `RecurringOrderLineTemplateId` column for example is unique then you can add `key: true` in the column and jqGrid will use the value as the rowid. If the composite key (`RecurringOrderHeaderTemplateId`, `RecurringOrderLineTemplateId`) is unique instead then you can fill `id` property with the values `item.RecurringOrderHeaderTemplateId + "_" + item.RecurringOrderLineTemplateId`. You will be able to get the values `RecurringOrderHeaderTemplateId` and `RecurringOrderLineTemplateId` from the rowid by usage `rowid.split("_")`. Setting good rowid will not solve your main problem, but it will save your time later.

The main problem in your existing code seems to me the usage of `$.grep` **over the whole data** inside of `formatDisplayField` callback. It seems me wrong from performance point of view and from the common design. The data of the grid are already groupped, but you try redo the same once more inside of every `formatDisplayField` call. I don't like it.

I'm not sure that I full understand what you try to implement. It seems to me that you set `data-rowdata` on the `<span>` element of the column header only to be able to use `$link.data('rowdata')` later inside of `click` handler of the context menu. You can add

```js
var $tr = $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgroup"),
    jqgrouplevel = parseInt($($tr).data("jqgrouplevel"), 10);
```

inside of `build` callback of the `contextMenu` and to use just

```js
edit: {
  ...
  callback: function () {
    for ($tr = $tr.next(); $tr.length; $tr = $tr.next()) {
        if ($tr.hasClass("jqgroup") && parseInt($tr.data("jqgrouplevel"), 10) <= jqgrouplevel) {
            break; // stop enumeration
        } else if ($tr.hasClass("jqgrow")) {
            $tr.addClass("markedForModification"); // mark the row
        }
    }
    //EditBillToHeader(rowData)
  }
```

The modified demo https://jsfiddle.net/dv4v8mmz/3/ uses the above code with some additional `alerts` in ".billToMenu" and in ".poMenu" (just duplicating the code). You can see that the approach works.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to make this work as a whole with my other code, I have removed the rowData get from the group formatter, and i am trying to get everything i need from the $tr variable that you created. I flag the rows as a visual to my users and then i take the data and send it to the server, I'll let you know as soon as I can if this resolves my issue.

Comment: @Noctane: The main part of your code will be executed **inside of context menu** created after the click on the grouping header. `$tr` represents the `<tr>` element of the clicked grouping header.

Comment: I think I got it working the way I need, I added delete, separated `mark()` into functions, and cleaned up the `formatDisplayField` function will you please check to make sure it is efficient? https://jsfiddle.net/y3llowjack3t/bj70cfsx/

Comment: @Noctane: The code looks better, but one can still improve and reduce it. The most important part is the loop in `loadComplete`. Instead of setting (changing!!!) the `title` you can better use `rowattr` callback. In the same way you can use `content` option of `tooltip` as **callback function** (see [here](https://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-content)). You can add one more class inside of `hintsButtonFormatter` formatter and to reduce many calls of tooltip to one which select by the class (like `$(".ui-icon-circle-zoomin").tooltip({...});`).

Comment: @Noctane: You can remove `style="cursor: pointer; color: blue;"` parts from all  `formatDisplayField` functions and to add one more CSS rule like: `.groupTypeMenu, .poMenu, .billToMenu { cursor: pointer; color: blue; }`. I'd recommend you additionally to use Font Awesome icons instead of old non-scaled jQuery UI icons. [The part of code](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.13.4/js/grid.base.js#L371-L507) shows names of the all standard icons in both cases.

Comment: Okay, will work on that too, Thanks so much again for your help.

Comment: Oleg - Just one more question, not sure it warrants a new SO question... In my Add new PO menu it is failing because the piece that gets the group type doesn't work at this level like it does at the order group type menu. Any idea how to get the name of the order group type at the po level? line 564 in fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y3llowjack3t/bj70cfsx/

Comment: nvm I think I got it working with `$tr.prev().find(".groupTypeMenu")`